# Spring XML Binding

Tags: xml, spring, rest

I am attempting to create a RESTful service that takes incoming XML and parses the results into a business object. I have the XML and the business object.

Is there a way to perform data-binding in terms of taking the xml coming into the RESTful service and automatically creating a business object.

Currently I am doing this part manually which I am pretty sure is not the best way to do this. I am thinking maybe there is way to map xml and transfer to object. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using an OXM (e.g. JAXB) and Spring Web MVC's `@RequestBody` annotation. Here's a simple RESTful example for creating a user object from an XML payload:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/users",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    headers = "content-type=application/xml")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String createUser(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletResponse res) {
    Long userId = userDao.create(user);
    response.addHeader("Location", "/users/" + userId);
    return null;
}
```

It sounds like you already have the XML payload part working so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I've used JAXB and it works quite well... except if you are dealing with Maps, then you need to deal with custom adapters.

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly what you're asking, but with JSON, using flexjson. I believe the package org.springframework.oxm contains a framework for serializing and de-serializing XML data, but I haven't personally tried it.

Comment: Yeah, you can use JAXB, Castor, JiBX, etc.